# Prophet symbol in LaTeX

Tags: symbols, arabic, ligatures

[image]

How do you get this symbol in LaTeX?

Comment: We need more information. For one thing, how are you compiling your documents? If you use `luatex` or `xetex`, then you can find this as a ligature in various fonts (e.g., [Scheherazade New](https://software.sil.org/scheherazade/)), which you’d use with `fontspec`.

Comment: @Thérèse I'm not sure. I use overleaf

Comment: In Overleaf, click on “Menu.” The first item under “Settings” is “Compiler.” What have you chosen?

Comment: @Thérèse pdfLaTeX

Comment: With `pdfLaTeX`, you may have to resort to using an image of the symbol. If you’re willing to switch to `XeLaTeX` or (even better) `LuaLaTeX`, they’re more powerful.

Comment: @Thérèse I don't really now how to use them. But if that's the only solution can you give a solution for those compilers as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways to work with the Arabic script. My preference is the `arabluatex` package, which requires you to choose `LuaLaTeX` as your compiler. With `arabluatex`, your desired output can be obtained as simply as this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\begin{document}
\begin{arab}
  \arbmark{slm}
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

That uses the default Amiri font.

If you wish to use a different font containing this ligature, then, before `\usepackage{arabluatex}`, add

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{put name of font here}[Script=Arabic]
```

Comment: Please, what is the significance of the arabic text in English language? :-) +1.

Comment: @Sebastiano “God bless him and grant him salvation!”

Comment: Hence you know the arabic language. Many compliments.

Answer (score 2):

1. Thanks for bringing this topic up.
2. I figured out another way using **KFGQPC Symbols** font in **XeLaTeX** and **Polyglossia**, fairly recently.
3. Here is an MWE for those interested;

```
    \documentclass{article}
    
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{arabic}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Scale=1.1,Script=Arabic]{KFGQPC Uthman Taha Naskh}
    \newfontfamily\symbolfont{KFGQPC Arabic Symbols 01}
    \newcommand{\salat}{{\symbolfont{\XeTeXglyph 41}}}
    \newcommand{\ranhu}{{\symbolfont{\XeTeXglyph 42}}}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \salat

    \ranhu

    \end{document}
```

Here what the resulting text looks like;
[image: Zathura and TeXMaker]

4. \salat would render the character defined for it and so-on for other  defined commands.
5. Refer this [PDF](https://archive.org/details/KFGQPCSymbolsGlyphTable) to see all the available glyphs.By the way you would need the KFGQPC Symbols font installed on your system.

Here is a preview;

[image: Glyph table preview]